# how to render a better startchart graph on umple?

Tags: graph, render, statechart, umple

The umple is a very good to design UML statecharts, with rich set of semantic attributes in text mode. However, the embedded mechanism to draw correspondent statechart has scarce resources to show important informations (e.g. guards, exit, entry, conditions).
Is there a safe interface to export/import on other tool, preserving all semantic of statechart?

Answer (score 1):

You make some good points.

Two parts of the answer is this

Issue 1863 is to have popups on state machines elements so the guards, exit, entry and other conditions. https://github.com/umple/umple/issues/1867
This is being worked on and is a high priority.

I just raided issue 1898 to add some more features https://github.com/umple/umple/issues/1898

As for exporting ... there is an NUSMV model generator. There is an experimental prototype scxml generator that needs more work too. The Papyrus generator also exports state machines, but also needs more work. These generators can be triggered by the GENERATE menu in Umpleonline or the -g command line argument

Core features of Umple are robust (e.g. Java code generation, and diagram generation, but your question delves into territory where more contributions would be welcome.